# Example of parametric and non-parametric method

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, nonparametric, distributions

I have not understood this [example from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics#Example).

> Suppose we have a sample of 99 test scores with a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 1. If we assume all 99 test scores are random samples from a normal distribution we predict there is a 1% chance that the 100th test score will be higher than 102.365 (that is the mean plus 2.365 standard deviations) assuming that the 100th test score comes from the same distribution as the others.

How did they compute that the $1$% chance of the $100$th test score will be higher than $102.365$ ?

And in non-parametric method why is `maximum` the estimate of the same thing of the $99$ scores ? Why `maximum` ? Why not the estimate is `average` of the $99$ scores? Why is there a $1$% chance(instead of 2%,3%,etc.) that the 100th is higher than any of the $99$ that preceded it ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Normal Distributions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution? In the parametric example they are assuming the data conforms to the normal distribution. In the non-parametric example, since they have 99 examples, they estimate the 100th percentile as the maximum of the 99 examples and thus make no parametric assumptions about the data.

Comment: Although I am a bit confused that the example used t-distribution with 98 df to get the 2.365. Given each reading is an individual score and not a sample mean.

Comment: **That example is incorrect.**  It assumes you know the *population* mean and *population* SD, but all you have is a sample of 99 values.

Comment: "If we assume all 99 test scores are random samples from a normal distribution"